# How to handle spaces in path names when variable contains multiple paths

Tags: bash, find, filenames, whitespace

Although I've read myself through most of the questions about handling spaces in path names, I haven't found my case yet, which is about **several** path names in one variable.

`find` will need this when two base paths are given, for example:

```
pa="/home/user/folder1 /home/user/folder2"
find $pa -name '*xy*' ...
```

This will look for matches in **both** `folder1` and `folder2`.

<sub>(Please note that this is a *simplified* example; I know very well that in this special case, you could use the `-path` modifier with a parameter like `folder*` that spans both folders. However, this question is to cover cases where you cannot work around the issue so easily due to higher complexity.)</sub>

---

Now imagine `folder2` contains a space in the middle. The following will **not** work:

```
pa="/home/user/folder1 /home/user/fol\ der2"
find $pa -name '*xy*' ...
```

The problem is the `\`, which is normally used to represent a space in the shell but will not work when the variable content is enclosed in double quotes.
However, unlike with **one** path per variable (where it might do the trick), the following won't work either:

```
pa=/home/user/folder1 /home/user/fol\ der2
find $pa -name '*xy*' ...
```

`$ ./test.sh: line 3: /home/user/fol der2: Is a directory`

nor will the following variant:

```
pa=/home/user/folder1 /home/user/fol\ der2
find "$pa" -name '*xy*' ...
```

---

So how can spaces be handled properly in paths if *several* paths are contained in one variable?

Related question: Is there any reliable way at all to determine whether a whitespace is a separator between one path and its successor (within the same variable), or a  whitespace that belongs to one of the paths contained within?

Comment: Well, duplicate or not: I think that in this case, nobody can accuse me of not having searched properly! Plus, I think that users will rather stumble on *my* question due to it's more descriptive title. On the question linked above, one is rather forced to delve through some remotely related stuff and imagine the rest...*What* you may think is duplicate here, is the section __"How do I process a list of file names?"__. However, I was asking about *path* names, not file names, that's why chances were high that I wouldn't necessarily stumble on question #131766.

Answer (score 5):

Use `bash` arrays:

```
pa=("/home/user/folder1" "/home/user/fol der2")
find "${pa[@]}" -name '*xy*' ...
```

#### Discussion

Observe that the `\` does not do what one hopes:

```
$ pa="/home/user/folder1 /home/user/fol\ der2"
$ printf '%s\n' $pa
/home/user/folder1
/home/user/fol\
der2
```

The `\` in the definition of `pa` becomes a literal character in the string, not an escape.  If you want a list of separate strings, use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array variable and put one path value in each element of the array. If that really isn't possible, another approach would be to use something other than *space* as your item separator.

```
p[0]="hello"
p[1]="happy"
p[2]="world"

echo "p[0]=${p[0]}, p[1]=${p[1]}, p[2]=${p[2]}"

for p in "${p[@]}"
do
    echo "p=$p."
done
```

Etc.